# How to create mobile version of my website

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile

I am new to mobile application.I worked php, html .. before and created websites using that

technologies.Now I have to create mobile version of that sites for example like m.url.com.

Please suggest me the easy and best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect lots of load; and want very good performance its advisable to develop native apps for each mobile type.
Otherwise developing in HTML5 should be good enough. You already know jquery-mobile is a very good platform to start developing the mobile version. It is easy too and very fast development. Once it is developed on HTML5; you can use phonegap to deploy it on all mobiles.

Regarding automatic conversion of normal website to mobile website: You can create a simple app (10 lines of code ) in which you would just invoke url.com and your app is ready.  User can double click on app and internally that app will just show url.com though user would feel as though he is accessing the app.

Talking about m.url.com which executes on browser of mobile:  your normal website will indeed work on mobile too; only challenge is smaller screen size and lots of possible sizes. So, we just need fluid layout and a new CSS which has dimensions as per smaller screen sizes.
If the original website is developed with mobile version in mind as future extension; then all you need to do is create an alternative css. Using Media-queries; it will automatically pick alternative css for mobiles.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say use Twitter Bootstrap for a quick responsive design, along with a commonly used CSS structure with a vast collection of themeable widgets.

Answer (score 2):

I world recommend learning java or objective-c.  Although I did a quick google search and came up with a few things that may work 
[link](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=convert+website+into+app&fp=d28097c313be9925)